# HREF is generating weird link

Tags: html, href

I defined a name tag on the page http://olderwomensnetwork.org/advocacy:

```
<a name="note"></a>
```

Then I referenced it (on the same page) like this:

```
<a href="http://olderwomensnetwork.org/advocacy#note">go to Note</a>
```

And it reported a not-found error for 
http://olderwomensnetwork.org/http:/olderwomensnetwork.org/advocacy#note
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my html example was treated as live html rather than as data.  Is it possible to ask questions about html here??

Comment: You just need to mark is as code in your post.  You can do it by starting each line with four spaces, or use the {} button on the toolbar.  mliebelt has done it for you in this case!

Comment: Yes, use the code button, which will place 4 spaces at the start of each line... this will automatically format your code for you. Check [the help for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: The page does not contain the link presented in the question, or any link referring to the anchor `note`.

Answer (score 5):

If you notice the error message you got, it is `http://olderwomensnetwork.org/http:/olderwomensnetwork.org/advocacy#note`

> ```
>                                  ^
> ```

You have missed a `/` in your link. That makes the browser think it is a relative URL and hence, the 404.

**Good Practice:** As you are using the `note` anchor for navigation within the page, specify the URL as 
`<a href="#note"..></a>`. It isn't necessary to specify the entire URL.

[W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.1)

[Links within a document](http://cti.itc.virginia.edu/~bcr/Labs/links.html)

Comment: Yes, that would normally be better, and it would normally be better to define the anchor by using `id="note"` on a suitable element rather than using an `a` element with empty content. But these do not explain why the method described in the question did not work.